# Rss feed layout in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, xml, rss

I want an `RSS` Feed displayed in an Android app.  Basically, it's reading from an `XML` file of course.  There are two items I want displayed in the Android `listView`:  `title`, `description`.

I want the feed to do this:

```
title
description

title
description

title
description

title
description
```

instead it is doing this:

```
title
title
title
title
title
title

description
description
description
description
description
description
```

I can see why based on how this code is, but I can't figure out how to layout like example number 1.

**Here is code:**

```
private class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attrs) throws SAXException {

        if (localName.equals("item")) {
            item = true;
        }

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
            fTitle = true;
        }

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
            fDesc = true;
        }

    }

    public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
            String qName) throws SAXException {

    }

    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {

        if (fTitle) {
            titleResult = titleResult + (new String(ch, start, length))
                    + "\t\n\n";
            fTitle = false;
        }

        if (fDesc) {
            rssResult = rssResult + (new String(ch, start, length))
                    + "\t\n\n";
            fDesc = false;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are maintaining two strings and combining them later, you should combine them as you build them. According to your example you should use something like this:

```
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {

    if (fTitle) {
        titleResult = titleResult + (new String(ch, start, length))
                + "\t\n";
        fTitle = false;
    }

    if (fDesc) {
        titleResult = titleResult + (new String(ch, start, length))
                + "\t\n\n";
        fDesc = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead you do it:

```
if (fTitle) {
        titleResult = titleResult + (new String(ch, start, length))
                + "\t\n\n";
        fTitle = false;
    }

if (fDesc) {
        rssResult = rssResult + (new String(ch, start, length))
                + "\t\n\n";
        fDesc = false;
    }
```

Look you are composing two strings one with a lot of titles and othr with a lot of descriptions.

Try to make a `List<String>` and add yours objects there:

```
List<String> feeds = new ArrayList<String>();
...
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
        throws SAXException {

    String feed = new String("");
    if (fTitle) {
        feed = new String(ch, start, length)
                + "\t\n\n";
        fTitle = false;
    }

    if (fDesc) {
        feed = feed + (new String(ch, start, length))
                + "\t\n\n";
        fDesc = false;
    }
    feeds.add(feed);
}
```

Then your can use a print to show your list:

```
for(String feed : feeds) {
  <Use your string>
  feed.doSometing();
}
```

But the best pratice are you make a Feed Object to store the title and the description, like:

```
List<Feed> feeds = new ArrayList<Feed>();
Feed feed = new Feed(title, description);
feeds.add(feed);
for(Feed feed : feeds) {
  feed.getTitle().doSometing();
  feed.getDescription().doSometing();
}
```

=)